# Можно ли использовать stylus и ng-cli в ionic?

Tags: angular4, ionic, stylus, angular-cli

Имею опыт разработки нескольких приложений на `Angular`. Использовал `ng-cli` и в качестве препроцессора `stylus`. Сейчас начал осваивать `ionic` и появилось 2 вопроса:

1. Можно ли использовать `stylus`? Или `ionic` подразумевает выбор `sass`?
2. Можно ли как-то подружить его с `ng-cli`? Или есть другие способы генерировать компоненты, сервисы и т.д.?